# If/and in an Excel index function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to automatically list the contents of the C column in Excel, only if the value in two other columns are "requirement", and "attract". Without the 'and' statement it seems to work, but when I add the AND statement, it just lists all the comments. Probably it influences the row count, but I cannot figure it out. The comments are in Sheet3, the result should be somewhere else.

| C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| comment 1 | Requirement | Convert |
| comment 2 | Wish | Attract |
| comment 3 | Requirement | Attract |
| comment 4 | Requirement | Attract |

So in the table above it should only retrieve 'comment 3' and 'comment 4'

Here is the function I am using:

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!$C$2:$C$127;SMALL(IF(AND(Sheet3!$D$2:$D$127="Requirement";Sheet3!$E$2:$E$127="Attract");ROW(Sheet3!$D$2:$D$127)-ROW(Sheet3!$D$2)+1);ROWS($D$2:$D2)))
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

Array formula do not play nice with `AND` or `OR` as they will take an array and return a single value and we need an array returned.

So we use `*` and `+` respectively.

```
(Sheet3!$D$2:$D$127="Requirement")*(Sheet3!$E$2:$E$127="Attract")
```

if you have office 365 FILTER would work better:

```
=FILTER(Sheet3!$C$2:$C$127;(Sheet3!$D$2:$D$127="Requirement")*(Sheet3!$E$2:$E$127="Attract"))
```

Without FILTER:

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!$C$2:$C$127;SMALL(IF((Sheet3!$D$2:$D$127="Requirement")*(Sheet3!$E$2:$E$127="Attract");ROW(Sheet3!$D$2:$D$127)-ROW(Sheet3!$D$2)+1);ROWS($D$2:$D2)))
```